# How can I install and browse Jenkins using https?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins service installed. I can browse the service via

```
 http://<jenkins_ip>:<port_number>
```

How can I configure and browse Jenkins via https on a Windows server?

So I'd like to be able to go to

```
https://<jenkins_ip>:<port_number>
```